# RuntimeError: Model class django_embed.models.SeaSurfaceTemperature doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in a

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I get this error when I try to import my model SeaSurfaceTemperature into views.py (line 16). I’ve researched the issue but none of the proposed fixes works for me. Here I my repo: https://github.com/theresemoreau/django_bokeh_test
I would so appreciate the help with fixing this issue.

I’m trying to learn to create a web app displaying an interactive bokeh visualization. Everything works perfectly when I import data from bokeh.sampledata (i.e. out-comment line 16). However, what I’m really interested in is importing data from a postgresql db via django model, so I downloaded the data set and put it into the table SeaSurfaceTemperature under the database teledataskandalen.

Answer (score 0):

Your code structure is not correct as per Django guidelines. This is the main culprit.

You need to create some app and add that models.py and other files related to the app to that module, once you add that then you have to install that app in settings.py. Post that it should work fine.

Django App structure

```
settings.py
urls.py
asgi.py
app/
    models.py
    views.py
    urls.py
    templates/
              xyz.html
```

Answer (score 0):

django_embed isn't on your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py that's the main culprit here.

As per the @sonus21's answer though, your project doesn't follow the normal Django structure. Your models should be in a separate app folder leaving settings.py, wsgi.py and so on by themselves.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/